# Chainlink node external adapter executes successfully, but keeps returning 0

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, chainlink

I'm trying to build an external adapter for a chainlink node to import API information. On the chainlink node and API, everything seems like it worked, however when I try to call the stored value from the smart contract, it's always 0 despite the logs indicating that it ran successfully.

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Mimi-Fund-EA"
externalJobID = "834d2179-321d-49ac-bf63-140635e3a606"
forwardingAllowed = false
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
contractAddress = "0xAf644831B57E5625ac64cDa68248b810bE4D4D01"
minContractPaymentLinkJuels = "0"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type=ethabidecodelog
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type=cborparse data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type=bridge name="mimifund" requestData="{\\"id\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \\"data\\": { \\"year\\": $(decode_cbor.year), \\"discount_rate\\": $(decode_cbor.discount_rate)}}"]
    parse        [type=jsonparse path="data,result" data="$(fetch)"]
    ds_multiply  [type="multiply" times=1000000000000000000]
    encode_data  [type=ethabiencode abi="(uint256 value)" data="{ \\"value\\": $(ds_multiply) }"]
    encode_tx    [type=ethabiencode
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type=ethtx to="0xAf644831B57E5625ac64cDa68248b810bE4D4D01" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> ds_multiply-> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
```

These are the run logs from the Node. Everything compiled just fine and the values look good however, they never update in a smart contract, it's always 0.

[image]

This is my smart contract for reference.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

contract mimifundCO2 is ChainlinkClient, ConfirmedOwner {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    uint256 public volume;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;

    event RequestVolume(bytes32 indexed requestId, uint256 volume);

    /**
     * @notice Initialize the link token and target oracle
     *
     * Goerli Testnet details:
     * Link Token: 0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB
     * Oracle: 0xCC79157eb46F5624204f47AB42b3906cAA40eaB7 (Chainlink DevRel)
     * jobId: ca98366cc7314957b8c012c72f05aeeb
     *
     */
    constructor() ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
        setChainlinkToken(0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB);
        setChainlinkOracle(0xAf644831B57E5625ac64cDa68248b810bE4D4D01);
        jobId = "834d2179321d49acbf63140635e3a606";
        fee = (1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY) / 10; // 0,1 * 10**18 (Varies by network and job)
    }

    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
     * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
     */
    function requestCO2PricingData(uint256 _year) public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);

        req.add('year', Strings.toString(_year)); // Chainlink nodes 1.0.0 and later support this format
        req.add('discount_rate', '0.0'); // Chainlink nodes 1.0.0 and later support this format

        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
    }

    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of uint256
     */
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
        emit RequestVolume(_requestId, _volume);
        volume = _volume;
    }

    /**
     * Allow withdraw of Link tokens from the contract
     */
    function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
        require(link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))), 'Unable to transfer');
    }
}
```

I feel like there is some update to either my fulfill function or submit_tx that I need to update, but I am out of ideas about what to change.

I've tried changing all the parameters and both the API and chainlink node accurate update and reflect the correct input. The smart contract seems to work perfectly, it's just that calling volume in the code always returns 0 and I've got no clue what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, Chainlink node received your request and run the job successfully, but failed to write the result back to your contract. There might be multiple reasons, but most likely something is wrong when the Chainlink node calls the function `fulfillOracleRequest2` in the [Operator.sol](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.7/Operator.sol) and fails to write the result back to your contract.

Please check the following:

1. Check if you fund your Chainlink node. You can check the balance of the chainlink node in the top right of the Chainlink node UI which is usually with port number 6688(eg. http://localhost:6688). Because the Chainlink node changes the state of the blockchain when calling the function in the contract operator, there has to be a minimum balance of ETH remaining in your Chainlink node. The solution to the issue is just to transfer some ETH(not LINK) tokens to your chainlink node address.
   [image]
2. Check if you grant the Chainlink node permission to call function `fulfillOracleRequest2` in the contract operator. Search your Chainlink node address in the blockchain explorer like [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/), [goerliscan](https://goerli.etherscan.io/), [polygonscan](https://polygonscan.com/), etc. and if the node has no permission to call function `fulfillOracleRequest`, error `Fail with error 'Not authorized sender'` will be thrown. The solution to the issue is to use the function `setAuthorizedSenders` to grant the node address permission to call the function `fulfillOracleRequest2`.